# XSLT 1.0: dynamically set node value based on value set for previous node

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am trying to set a value for a node based on a value that may or may not have been set for a previous node in a list.  I need to use XSLT 1.0 because this is being done within the IBM DataPower appliance.  There is more to it than this, but I think this breaks it down to the bare essentials.

I am trying to identify number ranges that have no preceding number ranges with overlapping numbers.  Once a number range has its IsUnique element set to true, all other overlapping number ranges following it MUST have their IsUnique element set to false.

If I have an XML doc that looks like this:

```
<Range>
    <Start>1</Start>
    <End>10</End>
    <IsUnique>true</IsUnique>
</Range>
<Range>
    <Start>11</Start>
    <End>20</End>
    <IsUnique>false</IsUnique>
</Range>
<Range>
    <Start>15</Start>
    <End>21</End>
    <IsUnique>false</IsUnique>
</Range>
<Range>
    <Start>25</Start>
    <End>30</End>
    <IsUnique>false</IsUnique>
</Range>
```

I want it to flip the IsUnique value on the second Range to "true" since its range does not overlap with any of the previous ranges.  I do NOT want it to flip the third one since its range overlaps with the second one.  I want it to flip the forth one to true since its range does not overlap with any of the previous ranges.  I am not able to figure out how to "see" that a previous node's IsUnique value has been flipped when processing subsequent nodes.  It sounds so simple and I suspect there is some simple solution I am missing, but I am not able to get it to work as desired.  I assume I need to use an RTF and exsl:node-set(), but I have not found the right incantation to get it to work.  Thanks!

Comment: Often, there is no use explaining a transformation in prose - show the expected output _as code_, that is, XML. Also, please include your current attempt at solving your problem - even if it does not work.

Comment: You say "*does not overlap with any of the previous ranges.*" Why is "previous" significant here? I would have thought that if **any** two (or more) ranges overlap they are not "unique" - is that not so?

Comment: A transform can't rely on  decisions made in past transforms unless (a) values are explicitly passed down the apply-templates call stack as parameters, or (b) the stylesheet performs multiple passes over the document. If I were implementing this, I'd start by redefining your algorithm so each node decides whether it overlaps by scanning all its preceding context -- there will be some wasted effort, but probably less than multiple passes would require, and it would let you write the stylesheet in a simpler, declarative manner. XSLT is a functional language; learn to use it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="IsUnique">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="not(../../Range[generate-id()!=generate-id(current()/..) and Start &lt;= current()/../End and End >= current()/../Start])"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your (corrected!) example input, the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Range>
      <Start>1</Start>
      <End>10</End>
      <IsUnique>true</IsUnique>
   </Range>
   <Range>
      <Start>11</Start>
      <End>20</End>
      <IsUnique>false</IsUnique>
   </Range>
   <Range>
      <Start>15</Start>
      <End>21</End>
      <IsUnique>false</IsUnique>
   </Range>
   <Range>
      <Start>25</Start>
      <End>30</End>
      <IsUnique>true</IsUnique>
   </Range>
</root>
```

---

### Added:

The above will flag any range that overlaps **any** other range, regardless of their position relative to each other.

To flag only ranges that overlap **previous** ranges (in document order), use:

```
<xsl:template match="IsUnique">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="not(../preceding-sibling::Range[Start &lt;= current()/../End and End >= current()/../Start])"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Revision:

After re-defining the task as follows:

1. Flag each range as either true or false (ignoring existing flags);
2. Flag a range as false if (and only if) it overlaps a previous range that was flagged true; the first range, by this definition, must be flagged as true.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:call-template name="process-ranges">
            <xsl:with-param name="ranges" select="Range"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="process-ranges">
    <xsl:param name="ranges"/>
    <xsl:param name="true-ranges" select="dummy-node"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="current-range" select="$ranges[$i]"/>
    <xsl:param name="unique" select="not(exsl:node-set($true-ranges)[Start &lt;= $current-range/End and End >= $current-range/Start])"/>
    <!-- output --> 
    <Range>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$current-range/Start | $current-range/End"/>
        <IsUnique>
            <xsl:value-of select="$unique"/>
        </IsUnique>
    </Range>
    <!-- recursive call -->
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt; count($ranges)">
        <xsl:call-template name="process-ranges">
            <xsl:with-param name="ranges" select="$ranges"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="true-ranges" select="$true-ranges | $current-range[$unique]"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Range>
      <Start>1</Start>
      <End>10</End>
      <IsUnique>true</IsUnique>
   </Range>
   <Range>
      <Start>11</Start>
      <End>20</End>
      <IsUnique>true</IsUnique>
   </Range>
   <Range>
      <Start>15</Start>
      <End>21</End>
      <IsUnique>false</IsUnique>
   </Range>
   <Range>
      <Start>25</Start>
      <End>30</End>
      <IsUnique>true</IsUnique>
   </Range>
</root>
```

Further testing would be in order.

Comment: Maybe the IsUnique element should be called isFirstUnique.  The XSL you have does find non-overlapping ranges, but I need the first one it finds that does not overlap any preceding ranges to have IsUnique set to true.  The order of the range elements has already been sorted due to this requirement.

Comment: Well, the adjustment is rather trivial and I am surprised you didn't come up with it yourself. I just hope you know what you are doing, since it makes very little sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for trying again, but I think you are missing the key problem.  The data is dynamic.  When an IsUnique element has been flipped from "false" to "true", it can affect any following elements since they can no longer be "true" if they overlap that element.  If the input data is like this 1-10,true 5-15,false 11-20,false  the output should be 1-10,true 5-15,false 11-20,true.  The third one is flipped because it only overlaps a preceding node with a "false" value".  Even if I tweak your approach, I will not "see" the new value because it is looking at the input node tree which is immutable.

Comment: I see. I don't think you have mentioned this requirement before, so let me see if I understand this correctly: you want to flag a range as false only if it overlaps a previous range that is flagged true. Would that be the correct (and complete) instruction? Do the initial states of the flag play any role in this, or can they be ignored?

Comment: The initial values can probably just be ignored.  The first one will always be true since it has no ranges preceding it.

Comment: I should probably also add that it would even be OK if it took two passes.  One pass to setup some data that the second pass could use and remove; i.e. two separate stylesheets.

Comment: @Bueller Have a look at the revised suggestion.

Comment: Impressive.  I think you have it.  I have spent a couple days trying to figure this one out.  Thanks!